# Chrome allow insecure localhost flag does not work with vhosts

Tags: apache, google-chrome, ssl, localhost, vhosts

I am setting up an apache developement environment on my computer. I want to work with virtual hosts and HTTPS, so I set up vhosts and SSL certificates with openssl as well.

Everything works fine, but I want to get rid of the security warning in chrome. After some googling I found out that setting the [allow-insecure-localhost](https://superuser.com/questions/772762/how-can-i-disable-security-checks-for-localhost) flag might get me closer to the solution.

After I set it, the https://localhost address worked fine without the warning, but when I'm trying to open a virtual host (let's say: https://www.example.com), chrome always throws me the warning message:

```
ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

I am using Apache/2.4.29 on a High Sierra MacOS. I have separate certificates for the different vhosts, and on apache startup the log tells me

```
AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername example.com found
```

So my question is, how to get rid of the chrome insecurity warnings on a local environment when I want to use secure vhosts?